# Best Practice to backup data?

Tags: backup, archive

New in the backup Engineer field, do you have some bests practices to give to common users from an SI of +2000 people to how to backup their data dated from +10 years please ?

Environment windows + linux. shared folder by department.

Thank you.

I tried to ask myself some questions, limit of folder's name, what need to be really saved for this long, do user need to keep all these datas for how long ? etc...